# MYSQL Removing duplicates in mixmatched order

Tags: mysql, duplicates

How can I remove duplicates in the following order

```
1 2
2 1
1 3
4 1
```

and only output

```
1 2
1 3
4 1
```

Comment: The first one could take precedence over the second. Either one would work however.

Comment: @Strawberry thank you, I updated my question to reflect this

Comment: What query generated these pairs?

Comment: @danblack a LEFT JOIN generated the pairs

Comment: @Strawberry the order is defined by distinct ordering in the table of the ids, I am not specifying any order within my query.

Comment: If the order of the columns didn't matter `SELECT  DISTINCT LEAST(col1,col2), GREATEST(col1,col2) FROM my_table` would be sufficient. A little more information in a question removes some guesswork by the answering party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,user1 INT NOT NULL
,user2 INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (user1,user2) VALUES
(1, 2),
(2, 1),
(1, 3),
(4, 1);

SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MIN(id) id
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY LEAST(user1,user2)
            , GREATEST(user1,user2)
     ) y
    ON y.id = x.id;
+----+-------+-------+
| id | user1 | user2 |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 |     1 |     2 |
|  3 |     1 |     3 |
|  4 |     4 |     1 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

Comment: I do not understand what the group by LEAST, GREATEST is doing

Comment: Try executing `SELECT *, LEAST(user1,user2), GREATEST(user1,user2) FROM my_table`

Answer (score -1):

Use [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) to merge duplicate.

Comment: This will not work because some rows are "1, 2" and "1, 3", this would remove the "1, 3"

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `DISTINCT` clause to remove duplicates. The `DISTINCT` command in SQL retrieves unique data from your table. To remove duplicates, you can issue a statement similar to below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column_Name
FROM Table_Name
```

> OUTPUT: 1 2 OR 2 1

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: DISTINCT will not work since the duplication is not in the same columns.